# Best library to unzip files in asp.net mvc3 and .net4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unzip

I run .NET 4.0 and cannot change over to .NET4.5 so cannot use the line:

```
 Decompress.CopyTo(destinationDirectoryName);
```

any good 3rd party libraries i can consider??
I need to unzip multiple files in a .zip

thanks

Comment: Have you tried with [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I use DotNetZip and am happy with it.  Very clean and easy to use.  I don't know if it's the 'best', but I like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is very good and easy to use.